# Error: constructor for a xyz class is not defined

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String md5(String in) {
        MessageDigest digest;
        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.reset();
            digest.update(in.getBytes());
            byte[] a = digest.digest();
            int len = a.length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
                sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String userid = text.getText().toString();
                String pass = text1.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Entered " + userid + " and password entered is "
                                + pass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                pass = md5(pass + "@string/salt");

                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "Password after adding a salt and md5 hashing is now equal to "
                                + pass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                /* This Line */DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); // This Line.
                db.open();
                Cursor c = db.getPasswordForUserName(userid);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    if (c.getString(1) == pass) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Authentication Succeded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                        // proceed
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "@string/AuthFail",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // AuthFailure
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "@string/UserNotFound",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // where to from here
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am very new to Android programming. So I have taken code snippets from a lot of places and then combined them.

Basically what all I want to do is to query a local SQLite DB for existing value of `UserName` and `Password` + `salt(with md5 hash)`.

So I copied some code to create a database helper class (`DBAdapter`), which had pretty basic methods to deal with the database.

The problem now is that in the `MainActivity.java` file. The line marked *"this line"* in the code gives the error *The constructor DBAdapter(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined.* I do not know what this means. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: I would advise anyone trying to learn Android to learn Java first. Specifically you are using a asking DBAdapter to accept a View.OnClickListener as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess
Try MainActivity.this , got a hunch..

```
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: The reason why this fix works is because you are calling the constructor form inside an OnClickListener. So "this" refers to the OnClickListener instance, not your activity's instance.

Comment: aah ! It did work ! And I understand the explanation ! Thanks @Jeffrey

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading more about how android works. In this particular case, you need to know about [Contexts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), but I would start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html).

As already suggested, you can use **MainActivity.this** to provide the DBAdapter with the correct application Context.